# How to use watch function in typescript language Vuejs?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I need to change this script from js to ts but i need syntax of watchers

```
export default {
    props: ['branch_id'],
    watch: {}
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First you have to declare your variable, like `myProperty` in this case, and then you have to make a `@Watch('myProperty')` to make the actual watcher for that specific variable.

```
@Component
export default class App extends Vue {
  myProperty: string

  @Watch('myProperty')
  onPropertyChanged(value: string, oldValue: string) {
    // Do stuff with the watcher here.
  }
}
```

Comment: This works for me, thanks! But how can I watch a prop? I tried the same syntax but it seems to never be executed